How to eliminate nested joins in generated SQL query?
I created a LINQ query in a .NET Core Application to retrieve some data. When checking the generated SQL for the LINQ I noticed nested queries in it. I want to optimize my LINQ query by removing the nested queries.
The LINQ query I tried:
from se in Context.SportEvents
where se.EventId == eventId
from eventMarket in se.EventMarkets
join marketOdds in Context.EventMarketOdds on eventMarket.Id equals marketOdds.EventMarketId into marketOddsGroup
from marketOdds in marketOddsGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join marketSpecifiers in Context.EventMarketSpecifiers on eventMarket.Id equals marketSpecifiers.EventMarketId into marketSpecifiersGroup
from marketSpecifiers in marketSpecifiersGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new SportEvent()
{
    Id = se.Id,
    EventId = se.EventId,
    EventType = se.EventType,
    Name = se.Name,
    EventStatus = se.EventStatus,
    ScheduledTime = se.ScheduledTime,
    ScheduledEndTime = se.ScheduledEndTime,
    EndedOn = se.EndedOn,
    IsHighlightedCard = se.IsHighlightedCard,
    IsHighlightedTopMatch = se.IsHighlightedTopMatch,
    IsOnline = se.IsOnline,
    SportId = se.SportId,
    TournamentId = se.TournamentId,
    EventMarkets = se.EventMarkets.Select(em => new EventMarket
    {
        Id = em.Id,
        EventId = em.EventId,
        MarketThirdPartyId = em.MarketThirdPartyId,
        MarketSportId = em.MarketSportId,
        MarketName = em.MarketName,
        IsActive = em.IsActive,
        IsFavorite = em.IsFavorite,
        EventMarketStatus = em.EventMarketStatus,
        EventMarketOdds = em.EventMarketOdds.Select(emo => new EventMarketOdds
        {
            Id = emo.Id,
            Odds = emo.Odds,
            OutcomeThirdPartyId = emo.OutcomeThirdPartyId
        }).ToList(),
        EventMarketSpecifiers = em.EventMarketSpecifiers.Select(ems => new EventMarketSpecifier
        {
            SpecifierName = ems.SpecifierName,
            SpecifierValue = ems.SpecifierValue
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList()
};

Generated SQL:
SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[EventId], [s].[EventType], [s].[Name], [s].[EventStatus], [s].[ScheduledTime], [s].[ScheduledEndTime], [s].[EndedOn], [s].[IsHighlightedCard], [s].[IsHighlightedTopMatch], [s].[IsOnline], [s].[SportId], [s].[TournamentId], [t].[Id], [t].[EventId], [t].[MarketThirdPartyId], [t].[MarketSportId], [t].[MarketName], [t].[IsActive], [t].[IsFavorite], [t].[EventMarketStatus], [t].[Id0], [t].[Odds], [t].[OutcomeThirdPartyId], [t].[SpecifierName], [t].[SpecifierValue], [t].[Id1]
FROM [Events].[SportEvents] AS [s]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [e].[Id], [e].[EventId], [e].[MarketThirdPartyId], [e].[MarketSportId], [e].[MarketName], [e].[IsActive], [e].[IsFavorite], [e].[EventMarketStatus], [e0].[Id] AS [Id0], [e0].[Odds], [e0].[OutcomeThirdPartyId], [e1].[SpecifierName], [e1].[SpecifierValue], [e1].[Id] AS [Id1], [e].[SportEventId]
    FROM [Events].[EventMarkets] AS [e]
    LEFT JOIN [Events].[EventMarketOdds] AS [e0] ON [e].[Id] = [e0].[EventMarketId]
    LEFT JOIN [Events].[EventMarketSpecifiers] AS [e1] ON [e].[Id] = [e1].[EventMarketId]
) AS [t] ON [s].[Id] = [t].[SportEventId]
WHERE [s].[EventId] = @__eventId_0
ORDER BY [s].[Id], [t].[Id], [t].[Id0]

The model classes are as follows:
class SportEvent { 
public int Id {get; set;} 
public string Name { get; set; } 
public List<EventMarket> EventMarkets { get; set; } 
} 

class EventMarket { 
public int Id { get; set; } 
public string Name { get; set; } 
public List<EventMarketOdds>? EventMarketOdds { get; set; } 
public List<EventMarketSpecifier>? EventMarketSpecifiers { get;set;} 
} 


It is slow? Have you tried to use AsSplitQuery()?

Why do you assume nested JOINs reduce performance? A far bigger problem is that instead of using EF to load objects through relations, it's used as if it was embedded SQL. SportEvent should have a Market or Markets properties, along with Odds, Specifiers etc. You can probably replace the entire query with Context.SportEvents.Include(e=>e.Markets).ThenInclude(e=>e.Odds)...Find(eventId). The query looks like it's trying to load all columns each time, so just forcing eager loading will do the same thing all those lines try to do

@SvyatoslavDanyliv No I haven't tried using AsSplitQuery(). Yes the performance with nested queries is bad.

@PanagiotisKanavos Will check with your approach

Efficient execution of your query would likely depend in the presence of the following indexes (or equivalent) to support your foreign key relationships and joins: SportEvents(EventId), EventMarkets(SportEventId), EventMarketOdds(EventMarketId), and EventMarketSpecifiers(EventMarketId). I suggest that you check to see if such indexes are defines, and add them if they are absent. If neither these nor the .AsSplitQuery() suggestions help, you need to manually execute the query, capture the execution plan, and post it using Post the Plan.

There's nothing inefficient about subqueries (not nested JOINs) anyway. For these specific queries the query analyzer will create the same execution plan as a query that specified all the tables in the outer query. What matters is having the proper indexes on the JOIN columns.

Is there any correct way to remove the nested joins from the generated queries please?

You don't need to remove anything, they generate same query

@siggemannen I do not need to have the nested queries

This is the execution plan for the desired SQL query can someone provide the LINQ equivalent for this?
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryK-KIjXC

At first, have you tried AsSplitQuery? Eager loading has no equivalent in the SQL, so EF Core may produce cartesian explosion of records. We cannot provide LINQ query without your model classes. Also post problematic execution plan.

SportEvent { public int Id {get; set;} public string Name { get; set; } public List<EventMarket> EventMarkets { get; set; } }
EventMarket { public int Id { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } public List<EventMarketOdds>? EventMarketOdds { get; set; } public List<EventMarketSpecifier>? EventMarketSpecifiers { get; set; } }
EventMarketOdds { public int Id }
EventMarketSpecifier { public int Id }
These are the model classes. I tried AsSplitQuery() but the requirement is to get the data without splitting the queries @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Edit question, do not post in comments requested information. If you tried to AsSplitQuery, it performs faster? If yes, you have no options, you have to do that via query splitting.

One problem that I see is that you have multiple independent one-to-many joins: EventMarkets to EventMarketOdds and EventMarkets to EventMarketSpecifiers. This will yield the cartesian-product of the two joins in your results. If for example, an EventMarket has 10 associated EventMarketOdds rows and 20 associated EventMarketSpecifiers rows, the query will yield 200 rows just for that one EventMarkets row.
Further, if you had a SportEvents row with multiple EventMarkets rows, the total result row count may be further multiplied. This data explosion may be causing your performance issues and possibly duplications in your final results.
I believe the solution is to just query the top level SportEvents rows in the initial query and then use .AsSplitQuery() to instruct EF to retrieve nested data as separate queries behind the scenes - one to retrieve the initial SportEvents data and potentially three more to retrieve the related EventMarkets, EventMarketOdds, and EventMarketSpecifiers data.
With a single query, the returned data can be heavily duplicated in cases like this.  EF has to separate and de-dup the data before the application sees it. Using .AsSplitQuery() avoids this extra cost, with the tradeoff of using a few additional, but much more efficient, queries. The result is the same from the application's perspective. This is a good thing.
I do not know the proper way to inject .AsSplitQuery() into LINQ query syntax, so I have coded the following up using LINQ method syntax.
(This is untested code. If I have made a error in syntax or usage, please post a comment, or even better, edit and apply the correction directly.)
var eventId = ...something...

var query = Context.SportEvents
    .Where(se => se.EventId == eventId)
    .Select(se => new SportEvent() {
        // Everything that follows is unchanged from the original posted query.
        Id = se.Id,
        EventId = se.EventId,
        EventType = se.EventType,
        Name = se.Name,
        EventStatus = se.EventStatus,
        ScheduledTime = se.ScheduledTime,
        ScheduledEndTime = se.ScheduledEndTime,
        EndedOn = se.EndedOn,
        IsHighlightedCard = se.IsHighlightedCard,
        IsHighlightedTopMatch = se.IsHighlightedTopMatch,
        IsOnline = se.IsOnline,
        SportId = se.SportId,
        TournamentId = se.TournamentId,
        EventMarkets = se.EventMarkets.Select(em => new EventMarket
        {
            Id = em.Id,
            EventId = em.EventId,
            MarketThirdPartyId = em.MarketThirdPartyId,
            MarketSportId = em.MarketSportId,
            MarketName = em.MarketName,
            IsActive = em.IsActive,
            IsFavorite = em.IsFavorite,
            EventMarketStatus = em.EventMarketStatus,
            EventMarketOdds = em.EventMarketOdds.Select(emo => new EventMarketOdds
            {
                Id = emo.Id,
                Odds = emo.Odds,
                OutcomeThirdPartyId = emo.OutcomeThirdPartyId
            }).ToList(),
            EventMarketSpecifiers = em.EventMarketSpecifiers.Select(ems => new EventMarketSpecifier
            {
                SpecifierName = ems.SpecifierName,
                SpecifierValue = ems.SpecifierValue
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList()
    })
    .AsSplitQuery()
    ; // Maybe a .ToList() here, if you wish execute the query immediately.

This could also be coded as a hybrid combination of LINQ query syntax and LINQ method syntax:
var query = (
        from se in Context.SportEvents
        where se.EventId == eventId
        select new SportEvent()
        {
            ...
        }
    )
    .AsSplitQuery()
    ; // Maybe a .ToList() here, if you wish execute the query immediately.


When a projection is used (Select...new) Includes are ignored. So either use Include or projection.

@GertArnold - Thanks for the feedback. So would the original query work efficiently after removing lines 3-7 leaving just from se in Context.SportEvents where se.EventId == eventId select new SportEvent() { ... }? (I wasn't sure what the purpose of the extra from...join...s were.) Does the mapping cause the nested data to be retrieved as part of the initial query as if the referenced tables (or a column subset) had been .Included? Would there be any benefit to using .Include(...).AsSplitQuery().AsEnumerable().Select(...). I may pull my answer if It's way off base and unsalvageable.

Remove Includes, which are ignored, and put AsSplitQuery() exactly before ToList().

A projection using navigation properties is always to be preferred over Including because Include queries all columns. Yes, navigation properties cause the nested data to be retrieved. EF will take care of the SQL joins.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv, GertArnold - I have updated the answer as suggested.

I use Query Expression Syntax when I have joins or SelectMany. IMHO, mixing both approaches is good and right practice in the right hands. In any case Query Expression Syntax is translated to Method Chain by the compiler.
